# SQL server datetimeoffset data aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently developing an application that makes use of an SQL database. In this database I maintain a table called session, which has three fields: a session id (int), a date_created (datetimeoffset), and a date_expired (datetimeoffset) field.

I want to group my sessions in clusters of sessions that the minimum date_created and the maximum date_expired of the sessions not to be more than 6 hours. Also, I don't want my groups to overlap, i.e. If session s1 belongs to group 1, I do not want it to be also in group 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Requirements unclear: Are you wanting to group them by Duration, or group them by start date, end date, hours or such that If one started at 8:00am and ended at 8:10am and another started at 9:00am and ended at 9:15 and another started at 2:01pm the first two would be "grouped together and the 2:01pm one would be in a second group (assuming same day for all)?

Comment: I want to group them by start date and end date. The only constraint should be that for two sessions in a set their time difference( between start date and end date) will not be more than 6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create your 4 data groups like 0-6, 6-12, 12-18 and 18-24, so you can do like this:

FYI: for the sake of simplicity, I did the `case` on the date column only, you will need to use a datediff between your date_created  and date_expired

FYI2: change the values on the between as it suits you better and in the end the query will return values to 1, 2, 3 and 4, which you should change to "0 to 6", "6 to 12" and so one..

```
with MyCTE as (
    select case 
            when datepart(hh,date ) between 0 and 6 then 1
            when datepart(hh,date ) between 6 and 12 then 2
            when datepart(hh,date ) between 13 and 18 then 3
            else 4
            end
          as myDatebucket 
    , *
    from session
) 
select myDatebucket, count(*)
from MyCTE
group by myDatebucket
order by myDatebucket
```